# Hibernate @Where clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc

I have User class, which has groups.

```
    @Where(clause = "enabled = 1 and deleted = 0")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }
```

But when I'm trying to make some operation on `Group` which is already stored in DB and is not suitable for `@Where` clause, Hibernate just ignores me.

Actually, `@Where` is not my decision, but solution I could find to overcome this (create another dao method to perform some operation) is so ugly.

So, is there way to overcome this? Or did I miss something?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may want to use Criteria API or named query as an alternative.

Comment: Please describe your problem precisely. Show the code that you're executing, tell us what you expect it to do, and tell us what it does instead.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the type of your `enabled` and `deleted` fields, you must write your `@Where` clause in a different form.

If your fields are numerics:

```
@Where(clause = "enabled = 1 and deleted = 0")
```

If your fields are Strings:

```
@Where(clause = "enabled = '1' and deleted = '0'")
```

If your fields are boolean:

```
@Where(clause = "enabled = true and deleted = false")
```

Check your types (in your Java class and in your database too) and use your `@Where` in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Use it with the table

`@Where(clause = "enabled = true") @Table(name= "user") public class User {}`