# JPA where clause condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate 3 within this mapping in `hbm.xml` file:

```
<class table="mtl_material_transactions" 
        name="com.kaka.oracle.model.inventory.transactions.MaterialTransaction" 
        where="transaction_type_id in (35,44,90)" 
        schema="apps">
```

The key point is `where`, how can I do the same with `JPA 2.0` *(hibernate 4.1.9 final as provider)*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@where` annotation, see this link for details:

[Hibernate @Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373368/hibernate-where-clause)

For example your entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mtl_material_transactions", schema="apps")
@Where(clause="transaction_type_id in (35,44,90)")
public class MaterialTransaction {
   ...
}
```